# Cannot persist cookies when using RTK Query

Tags: cookies, redux, react-redux, credentials, rtk-query

I'm creating a pet project with React with Redux on the front end and Node.js with express on the back end. It's the first time I use Redux and RTK Queries, and I'm confused about cookies not being saved.

I tried both variants with **RTK Query**, and neither worked for me.

```
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl,
  credentials: "include",
});
```

and

```
signIn: builder.mutation<User, SignInPayload>({
  query(body) {
    return {
      url: "/auth/jwt",
      method: "POST",
      body,
      credentials: "include",
    };
  },
}),
```

If I reach the same endpoint using **axios** and `{withCredentials: true}`, everything works fine, and cookies are persisted.

I attach my Request/Response Headers below.

[image]